# My formula in Google Sheets doesn’t add up to the same total in Yahoo?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google, yahoo

**Link:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KcYqRRqxZ3GWNAIUWgg9AGraTAzkrVxkDrk4ZsI5axY/edit?usp=sharing

So I do sports spreadsheets for fantasy sports. I’m filling out my baseball spreadsheet right now and I'm planning on doing this for football too if it works. A couple weeks ago I learned that you can make the spreadsheet calculate the number in a cell based on the numbers in other cells by making a formula. This helps shave off a lot of my workload.

Right now I’m trying to get it to calculate fantasy points.

A pitcher gets:

- 5 points for a Win
- 5 points for a Save
- -0.5 points for an earned run
- 1 point for an inning pitched
- 2 points for a strikeout

—————

- Wins are in the M column
- Saves are in the N column
- Earned runs are in the O column
- Innings pitched is in the L column
- Strikeouts are in the P column

**So my formula is:**

=M3*5+N3*5+O3*-0.5+L3*1+P3*2

Some of them are right on the money. I’ve put in eight of them. 3 are exactly correct. 4 of them, the decimal is wrong, 1 of them is off by a whole ten points. I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome. The likelihood is that there is an issue with the order of precedence. Please provide an actual example where the results difference from the expected results.

Comment: I can’t imagine that the order they’re in is the problem because it’s just addition. The worst of them is Verlander. Yahoo says he got 896 fantasy points this year, but the spreadsheet says he got 906. Like I said before, the other ones are just off by their decimals.

Comment: Did you try to do the calculation by hand to double check the results ? Anyhow we need you to provide us more data  in order to help you.like a public sheet

Comment: Alright I made a public version and posted the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KcYqRRqxZ3GWNAIUWgg9AGraTAzkrVxkDrk4ZsI5axY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the  Verlander data That is the only one in your example that doesn't calculate the expected value.

The other discrepancy is that you have misunderstood partial innings. X.1 means x & 1/3 innings not x & 1/10  innings. All except Verlander will be correct when you make that adjustment.

Comment: Yep that’s it! Thank you!!!

Comment: I’m an idiot. Verlander pitched 223 innings not 233. It was a typo haha

Comment: And an Aussie who knows nothing about Baseball, learns something new about decimals ;-)